# Search and copy the text between two markers in gvim

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste

I want to copy strings that spans across multiple lines between two markers in a large file.

In the below example file, start marker is `<ROW>` and end marker is `</ROW>`.

```
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>ANIMAL</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>123.75</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>DOG100</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>ANIMAL</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>150.00</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>DOG200</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>ANIMAL</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>170.00</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>CAT300</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>BIRD</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>200.00</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>PARROT300</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
.
.
.
```

I want to search and copy the string between `<ROW>` and `</ROW>` (including) that matches the text DOG

Example output

```
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>ANIMAL</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>123.75</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>DOG100</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <SOURCE>ANIMAL</SOURCE>
    <QTY>1.00</QTY>
    <UNIT_PRICE>150.00</UNIT_PRICE>
    <NARRATIVE>DOG200</NARRATIVE>
    <OUR_REFERENCE>BILLING</OUR_REFERENCE>
</ROW>
```

How can I do this in gvim?

Answer (score 3):

If you have [indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object/tree/5c5b24c959478929b54a9e831a8e2e651a465965), you could do something like

```
:global/DOG/normal "Ayii
```

I haven’t come up with a simple vanilla answer yet, but maybe

```
:global/DOG/ ?ROW?,/ROW/yank A
```

[@Lie Ryan](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23333/10604) reminded me of the `at` text-object, giving

```
:global/DOG/normal "Ay2at
```

Otherwise I’d use a dedicated XML parser and copy the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML/XML tag text object:

```
:g/DOG/norm v2at"AY
```

Or if you have a way to [reformat the XML afterwards](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Pretty-formatting_XML), then this shorter command also works:

```
:g/DOG/norm y2at
```

Both should work in standard vim without plugins.